# passwords match, but if statement fails

Tags: php, if-statement

I recently had a conversation that led me to the discovery that I've been storing passwords improperly. I've always used md5 and thought it was secure enough. However after some reading I've discovered is not the case, thus I am making the switch to bcrypt

Anyways, I'm creating the login processor, but once I encrypt the user supplied password with the known salt, it states that the passwords are not equal, however when I echo them, they are identical.

Here is the code:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

/*find that username in the database and grab their info*/
$check_username = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $query_username = $conn->prepare($check_username);
            $query_username->execute(array($username));
                $count = $query_username->rowCount();

    if($count > 0)/*if the user was found in the database*/
        {       
while($row = $query_username->fetch())
            {
                $salt = $row['salt'];
                $password_encrypted = $row['password'];
                $encrypt_password = crypt($password, $salt);

                if ($encrypt_password == $row['password'])
                    {
                        echo "success";
                    }
                else
                    {
                        var_dump($encrypt_password);
                        echo "<br />";
                        var_dump($row['password']);
                    }
            }
}
```

Not sure why this if statement fails hopefully one of you can see what I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Out put of vardumps:

```
string(60) "$2y$09$l2j89a6l7eoaz4dqpn5xzeAyBP1l7QzQuT7rIj8qYWX1/qJz7MYee" 
string(61) "$2y$09$l2j89a6l7eoaz4dqpn5xzeAyBP1l7QzQuT7rIj8qYWX1/qJz7MYee"
```

Found the error, I am using binary as for the column changing the string to 60 solved the issue. Thanks for the advice on using vardump

Comment: Do `var_dump()` instead of `echo`.

Comment: You are comparing an `encrypted` password with `normal` one, and, your `$password` variable is not defined.

Comment: @NOX $password is user supplied, above the code I pasted, and $row['password'] is already encrypted from the signup form

Comment: encrypted pass:
$2y$09$l2j89a6l7eoaz4dqpn5xzeAyBP1l7QzQuT7rIj8qYWX1/qJz7MYee
and one stored in the db:
$2y$09$l2j89a6l7eoaz4dqpn5xzeAyBP1l7QzQuT7rIj8qYWX1/qJz7MYee character per character are the same

Comment: I can't find where you define `$password` actually, can you show me? Btw, use this inside the code: `var_dump($encrypt_password);` and `var_dump($row['password']);`. And compare the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `echo` or at least don't use it without hard boundaries. Otherwise you have the same situation as the following two lines which seem to generate the same output:

```
print "hello"
print "hello     "
```

Use `var_dump` or, if you *must* echo, echo the variables in such a way that the HTML renderer doesn't stuff up your output, such as using `<pre>` tags with `[` and `]` delimiters.

Comment: hey bud, ive only echo those variables to see what they are storing, once it is working it would be removed

Comment: @Owen that's not the point...you'd remove the `var_dump` statements too. The point is that `var_dump` is specifically designed for debugging purposes and seeing what variables contain, and is much better than `echo` for that purpose.

Comment: @Owen, that's okay, you should _still_ not use `echo` since it can be modified in the background. For example, consider the string `"<hr />"` which is likely to insert a horizontal rule divider into the middle of your web page rather than printing out its actual content :-) `var_dump` will fix that.